# Python multidimensional interval calculations library

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, intervals

### Question

**Is there a library like [portion](https://pypi.org/project/portion/) or [interval](https://pyinterval.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) available that can work in multiple dimensions?**

#### Examples

*Note*: for the following examples, I use the following writing style:

- `{}` for collection of rectangles (to be generalized to hyperrectangles)
- outer `[]` for a single rectangle, containing the interval it occupies on each axis
- inner `[]` a single interval on a single axis.

For instance **union** of two rectangles
`{[[1, 20], [3,4]]} | {[[1, 20], [4,5]]}`
should give
`{[[1, 20], [3,5]]}`
while two disjoint rectangles should just become a collection of those two, similar to how interval libraries handle 1D intervals:
`{[[1, 20], [3,4]]} | {[[30, 40], [4,5]]}`
should give
`{[[1, 20], [3,4]] , [[30, 40], [4,5]]}`  .

And **intersection** of two rectangles
`{[[0, 10], [0,10]]} & {[[2,11], [3,5]]}`
should give
`[[2,10], [3,5]]`.

Note that the examples are limited to two dimensions for simpliciyt, but I am looking for a library that can handle even more (4 at least)

#### Found so far

I searched for libraries, but could only find:

- one-dimensional libraries like `portion` and `interval`
- polynomial libraries, which are both over-powerful in the 2d space (allowing general polynomials instead of only rectangles) and therefore likely sub-optimized for my applications, and don't support more than two dimensions